# Is there an easy way to check out the market cap of the alternative cryptocurrencies?

Tags: alternatives

Ideally, I'd like to see a pie chart with the whole pie being "Bitcoin-derived cryptocurrencies", and each major alternative represented as a market cap in Bitcoins and USD.

Currently, from what I gather we have:

- **Bitcoin** - 7,415,750 BTC = $34,854,025 = 99.7%
- **Namecoin** - 959,150 NMC = 25,897 BTC = $121,716 = 0.3%

I don't know where to get data on other cryptocurrencies right now, and if they even have any significant market cap.

Comment: Now that I think of it, building a site that shows up to date stats on this is super easy with a bit of javascript (at least for these two). I might make one this weekend if I find a few hours.

Comment: And ... done! http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-out-the-market-cap-of-the-alternative-currencies/1399#1399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dustcoin.com/mining is the only site I know right now that shows this information.

Answer (score 5):

Introducing ... [Bitcoin Pie](http://bitcoinpie.com/).

Supported Coins are Bitcoin, Tenebrix, NameCoin and SolidCoin. If your favorite coin is not supported, point me towards an active exchange (with or without an API), and a block explorer, and I'll integrate it.

Comment: Good stuff! One of these days I really must learn regex. I get 99% of your code but the regex might as well be written in Sanskrit :P

Comment: @David - Really? The regex is the simplest part of the code to me. There are a lot of inner closures there, I assumed that would be most complex.

Comment: It's not necessarily that the regex is complex for what it is, it's just that I never ever bothered to learn it at all. Not sure how I got this far in my career without learning it but perhaps it's time... I'm off to find some good resources.

Comment: Difficulty/hashrate would be a great thing to have in there too, since it approximates network security.  Great site, though!

Comment: @eMansipater - I'll put those up when I get a chance (code is open source, anyone is invited to send a pull request)

Comment: Site is dead right now, I haven't maintained it in a while (pull requests welcome).

Answer (score 2):

At the moment I don't believe there is any such site. It wouldn't be too hard to create, I might even do it myself, I just need to find a good data source for pricing.

The coin counts can be found easily here:

- [Bitcoin](http://blockexplorer.sytes.net/chain/Bitcoin/q/totalbc)
- [Fairbrix](http://blockexplorer.sytes.net/chain/Fairbrix/q/totalbc)
- [GeistGeld](http://blockexplorer.sytes.net/chain/GeistGeld/q/totalbc)
- [I0coin](http://blockexplorer.sytes.net/chain/I0coin/q/totalbc)
- [Ixcoin](http://blockexplorer.sytes.net/chain/Ixcoin/q/totalbc)
- [Namecoin](http://blockexplorer.sytes.net/chain/Namecoin/q/totalbc)
- [SolidCoin](http://blockexplorer.sytes.net/chain/SolidCoin/q/totalbc)
- [Tenebrix](http://blockexplorer.sytes.net/chain/Tenebrix/q/totalbc)

Given an API to pull price data from, calculating the numbers would be trivial, after which it's just a matter of how pretty a chart you'd like. I have a question [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/does-btc-e-have-an-api-for-alternate-currencies) if anyone knows of such a data source at which point I'd be happy to whip up just such a chart.

Comment: I beat you to it (only Namecoin and Bitcoin are supported so far)

Comment: Eh, Namecoin is easy. Wake me up when you've got APIs for all the others ;)

Comment: Added Tenebrix :) I'm surprised at its relatively high cap. When API fails, I'll go regex (already implemented it for Namecoin)

Comment: Added SolidCoin.

Answer (score -1):

It's 2021 and **none** of the existing answers work.

Behold [coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/).

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This is literally the only answer that actually works in 2021. Downvoter, don't cower behind your computer: speak up.