# Does BTC-E have an API for alternate currencies?

Tags: development, exchanges

BTC-E appears to have an API available at https://btc-e.com/api/1/ticker but this only lists the BTC/USD pair data. They also offer pairs of BTC against alternate currencies like Ixcoin and Tenebrix. I've tried the obvious stuff a la [https://btc-e.com/api/**2**/ticker](https://btc-e.com/api/2/ticker) but no dice.

I'll take an API from any other multi-currency exchange as well, really I just need a way to grab price easily from code without having to scrape HTML and deal with regex.

Comment: I am interested in this, too. Sent a PM yesterday but no answer yet.

Comment: @phelix - see my answer. Not the best answer, but this is what we have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The URL to the api's for other currencies are:

1. https://btc-e.com/api/2/1/ticker - BTC/USD
2. https://btc-e.com/api/2/2/ticker - IXC/BTC
3. https://btc-e.com/api/2/4/ticker - I0C/BTC
4. https://btc-e.com/api/2/5/ticker - SC/BTC
5. https://btc-e.com/api/2/6/ticker - SC/USD
6. https://btc-e.com/api/2/7/ticker - GG/BTC
7. https://btc-e.com/api/2/8/ticker - TBX/BTC
8. https://btc-e.com/api/2/9/ticker - FBX/BTC
9. https://btc-e.com/api/2/10/ticker - LTC/BTC
10. https://btc-e.com/api/2/11/ticker - RUC/BTC
11. https://btc-e.com/api/2/12/ticker - RUC/USD
12. https://btc-e.com/api/2/13/ticker - NMC/BTC
13. https://btc-e.com/api/2/14/ticker - LTC/USD
14. https://btc-e.com/api/2/15/ticker - CLC/BTC
15. https://btc-e.com/api/2/16/ticker - DVC/BTC

In the links below change the 1 to a number anywhere between 1-16 to match the category above.

Api for trades: https://btc-e.com/api/1/trades

Api for depth: https://btc-e.com/api/2/1/depth

Api for ticker: https://btc-e.com/api/2/1/ticker

By: dodoking

Comment: Looks like they finally implemented the /api/#/... stuff for the alternate currencies. As for the number of links, keep asking & answering questions, you get more privileges with more rep, and that includes more links. Right now the automated system is still trying to decide if you're a spammer or not ;)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on the privileges. Glad I could help with the information on the API's :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a working API, if all you need is the price then you can just parse their html. I just [used](https://github.com/ripper234/Bitcoin-Pie/) these regexes for the min/max prices and averaged them:

```
<span id='min_price'>(\\d+(?:\\.)\\d+)
<span id='max_price'>(\\d+(?:\\.)\\d+)
```