# Litecoin Historical Trade Data

Tags: litecoin, historical-trade-data

Is there anywhere I can find detailed LTC historical trade data? BTC-E's API is not well documented and I can only find a [live tick](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/2602) API from them. I found historical data on [Cryptocoin Charts](http://www.cryptocoincharts.info/period-charts.php?period=alltime&resolution=day&pair=ltc-btc&market=btc-e) but the data they output is not very detailed.

Answer (score 1):

If you search through your BTC-e's profile, you will find that they have MetaTrader which shows all trades.

This site shows data for MTGox which is very good for like how you want though I don't know if they have one for BTC-e

http://www.quandl.com/BITCOIN-Bitcoin-Charts/MTGOXUSD-Bitcoin-Markets-mtgoxUSD

Comment: The URL you linked 404s

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try http://www.cryptodatasets.com/ It has free raw data and sampled data from Bitfinex and HitBtc (currently), including BTC, ETH and LTC(litecoin).
Hope it helps!

P.S. it's my website

Comment: How did you obtain this data, and do you have the same for BitFinex IOTA/USD or IOTA/EU?

Comment: I think your BitFinex BTCUSD data is wrong. If I look at 2017-12-18 in BitFinex I see a high of about $19k and a low of about $10.5k. Your data says the highest high was $19,175 (looks right) and the lowest low was £18,010 (definitely wrong).

Comment: @PeterMorris I obtain the data via platform's API.
I will add MUCH more data (including IOTA/USD) quite soon.
Also, I am afraid that you are wrong since 2017-12-18 OHLC was: 18956, 19175, 18010, 18928

Comment: You are correct. I was looking at a graph from a non-BitFinex source and, of course, the values are exchange specific rather than a global price :)